# Почему перегрузка постфиксного и префиксного оператора++ в C# это один метод, а в С++ - два?

Tags: c#, c++, перегрузка-операторов

Не понимаю, как работает перегрузка в C#, с плюсами всё ясно.
Как метод выполняет и префиксную, и постфиксную функцию?
Опишите максимально подробно, пожалуйста.

код на C#:

```
    public static Car operator ++(Car car) // ++ один префикс и постфикс!
    {
        return new Car{ benzine = car.benzine + 1};
    }
```

код на C++:

```
Car& Car::operator++()
{
   this->benzine++;
   return *this;
}
Car Car::operator++(int unused)
{
   Car car = *this;
   ++this->benzine;
   return car;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C# имеется только оператор Increment. Если он пишется до значения, то в качестве результата компилятор использует новое значение, если после - то старое. При этом входящей переменной в обоих случаях присваивается новое значение. А входящий объект не изменяется, причем в случае префиксного оператора ссылка на него просто теряется.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Dummy
    {
        private String m_tag;

        public Dummy(String tag)
        {
            m_tag = tag;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return m_tag;
        }

        public static Dummy operator ++(Dummy initial)
        {
            return new Dummy("mutated");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var original = new Dummy("original");
            {
                var input = original;
                var output = ++input;
                Debug.Assert("original" == original.ToString());
                Debug.Assert("mutated" == input.ToString());
                Debug.Assert("mutated" == output.ToString());
                Debug.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(input, original));
                Debug.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(output, original));
                Debug.Assert(Object.ReferenceEquals(input, output));
            }
            {
                var input = original;
                var output = input++;
                Debug.Assert("original" == original.ToString());
                Debug.Assert("mutated" == input.ToString());
                Debug.Assert("original" == output.ToString());
                Debug.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(input, original));
                Debug.Assert(Object.ReferenceEquals(output, original));
                Debug.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(input, output));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В С++ это два совершенно раздельных оператора. Причем обычно подразумевается модификация объекта на месте, а ребиндинг ссылок вообще не допускается.